# How to avoid race conditions when Python talks to Pascal?

Tags: python

So, originally I was doing something that was meant to go like this:

```
Pascal_program : write file A
Pascal_program : call Python_program using ShellExecute
Python_program : open file A
Python_program : do the thing to the data
Python_program : write file B and shut down
Pascal_program : read file B
```

However, Pascal_program would start reading file B as soon as it had called Python_program and so before Python_program had had a chance to write to file B. After some trial and error, I came up with this, which worked last week:

```
Pascal program : delete file D (for "dummy"), if it exists
Pascal_program : write file A
Pascal_program : call Python_program using ShellExecute
Python_program : open file A
Python_program : do the thing to the data
Python_program : write file B
Python_program : create file D and shut down
Pascal_program : repeat until FileExists(D)
Pascal_program : read file B
```

It's stopped working. Apparently I was just tipping the balance towards the Python rather than (as I would have thought from the code) handing it the victory every time. It's now losing the race again.

And yes, it definitely is the race condition come back to haunt me and not some other blunder on my part — I can fix the problem again just by inserting a delay command before the last line. But this is not a great place in my program to be inserting gratuitous delays.

I don't see why my first fix doesn't work, does Python somehow multitask those disc operations? Or the operating system? (Windows 10 if it's relevant.) Or is the operating system no longer deleting file D in time? And more importantly, can someone tell me what I ought to do instead? My solution struck me as clumsy anyway, I'm having to do quite sophisticated things in Python without much background in it and it shows. Presumably there's some sort of standard approach to these issues.

Thank you for your advice.

---

OK, fixed. So, it turns out that in my extremely amateurish way I didn't know about the existence of processes. What I needed was to call it like this instead of using ShellExecute. Thank you Serge Ballesta — and stackoverflow generally, this is such a great resource that this is the first time I've actually had to ask a question.

```
Pr:= TProcess.Create(nil);
Pr.Executable:= filepath1+'python.exe';
Pr.Parameters.Add(filepath2+python_program_name+'.py');
Pr.Options := Pr.Options + [poWaitOnExit];
Pr.ShowWindow := swoHide;
Pr.Execute;
Pr.Free;
```

Comment: I have not used Pascal for decades, but any other language I know (C, Python, Java) have a function (generally `wait`) to make a program that has started a child process wait for the end of that child.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, ah, I see. I didn't know about processes, I've never needed to use them before, I was just using ShellExecute raw as it were. So I create a process to call the Python, execute the process, and then tell the Pascal to wait 'til the process is done. Seems simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly. I did not immediately see that you were using `ShellExecute`. This is a wrong tool here because it does not give you any handle to the subprocess. Depending on your environment (which Pascal on which platform) you could have other ways to start subprocesses. At leas `ShellExecuteEx` if it is available, or you could search whether a `system` function exists.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, got it working perfectly now, thanks. You will think me very ignorant I'm sure — and so I am, I'm having to do things beyond my experience 'cos no-one else can do them at all. Your post was a big help.

Comment: IMHO, as you have learned something, you could post a self answer and accept it. It could help future readers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use processes rather than using ShellExecute: the Pascal code is given in my edited OP and anything using Windows will be similar.